# How to do like between two strings separated by , in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have values in database as string stored as 1234,5678 how can i do get list of all values which have any one of the value in database

if i do select * from students where room_number like '1234,5678';

it give empty only values which have both numbers how to get all which belongs to '1234' '5678' and '1234,5678'

Comment: You should change the way the data is stored in the database. Please see this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, you'll have to split comma-separated values into rows.

I'm not sure what you mean by saying that someone's room number can really be `1234,5678` but hey - you probably do; that's what the `UNION ALL` part of the query does.

```
select *
from students s
where s.room_number in (-- split string into rows, i.e. separate '1234,5678' to
                        -- '1234' and '5678'
                        select regexp_substr(t.string, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)
                        from other_table t cross join
                          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(t.string, ',') + 1
                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
                        union all
                        -- this is a value you have in that other table "as is" 
                        -- (i.e. '1234,5678')
                        select t.string
                        from other_table t                                             
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split the list into separate terms.

You can use `LIKE` and surround the list and the matching values with the list delimiter:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   students
WHERE  ',' || :yourList || ',' LIKE '%,' || room_number || ',%';
```

Which for your (hard-coded) values would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   students
WHERE  ',1234,5678,' LIKE '%,' || room_number || ',%';
```

---

If you have the values stored in another table then you can `JOIN` based on `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM   students s
       INNER JOIN other_table o
       ON (',' || o.room_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || s.room_number || ',%');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (id, room_number) AS
SELECT 1, '1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '5678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '1234,5678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '9999' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE other_table (room_list) AS
SELECT '1234,5678' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ROOM_NUMBER |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1234 |
> | 2 | 5678 |
> | 3 | 1234,5678 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1b9e358c49a27f412f48295088825dcb)*